# Memoir header for article

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I am writing an `article` with `memoir` and the `\pagestyle{ruled}` is very nice but it keeps displaying *CONTENTS* every even (left) page (which I believe is a `Chapter`, but being my paper an `article` there are no chapters at all!).
What I would like to achieve is having the `Section` title (not in capitals) with its number on every page (with left/right alignment respectively), and the number centred at the bottom.
I know that the documentation is exhaustive, but the deadline is closer then ever and, unfortunately, I cannot dig into it right now. Moreover I couldn't find other questions with related purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility, with a slight variation on the `ruled` page style:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeatletter
\makeheadposition{myruled}{flushright}{flushleft}{flushright}{flushleft}
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeheadrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makepsmarks{myruled}{\@ruledmarks}
\makeevenhead{myruled}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{myruled}{}{}{\leftmark}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myruled}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second section}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost! Instead of the `Chapter` I wanted to display the current `Section` (since I am writing an article there are not chapters but only sections in my paper).

Comment: @Atcold using `memoir` with the `article` option, `\chapter` acts as `\section` in the standard `article` class.

Comment: Ok, in my situation I've been using `\section` anywhere (and 'fixed the numbering'), so how could I overcome this and point to my sections?

Comment: @Atcold but what you are doing produces inconsistencies; the ToC, LoF, LoT, references will have different headings (titles) than your sections, and there might be additional issues. In any case, change `\leftmark` to `\rightmark` in both places in my code above and see if it helps. I would suggest you, instead, to keep the intended structure for the sectional units.

Comment: Awesome! Since you are so knowledgeable, could you please point me out also how to number every and each line (footnotes included)? I have opened another question [here] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127637/line-numbering-the-whole-mainmatter-in-memoir) about it.

Comment: About the inconsistencies, I am not too sure to understand your point. This is [my TOC](http://i.stack.imgur.com/byjcE.png) and it looks fine, I guess.. Perhaps it could make more sense to view the `subsection` on the odd (right) pages, but this is not essential.. although it would be nice to know how it could be possibly done :)

Comment: Yes, sorry; I meant an inconsistency in the entries in the ToC; if you use `\section`, entries will be typeset as section entries in a book, which is different from using `\chapter`.

Comment: Hum.. I'm still confused.. I am using the `article` document style, which does not have chapters..

Comment: @Atcold didn't you say in your question that you are using `memoir` with the `article` option?

Comment: Ok, sorry, you are correct, `memoir` with `article` option. But I didn't get your last comment anyway. Sorry for being that cumbersome.. Actually I started with `article` and then I moved to `memori` `article` and that's why there have been the confusion and mess with the incorrect usage of the correct syntax.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10066/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-atcold)

Comment: Hem.. could you please check the chat? ^^ Then I will remove this comment ;)