# Line numbering the whole mainmatter in memoir

Tags: memoir, line-numbering

Ok, now I am panicking, since `lineo` cannot be used with `memoir` (using `\RequirePackage{lineno}`).
The specifications for the paper I am writing are *numbering the `mainmatter`, footnotes included* for reviewing purpose.
Well, I am struggling to find out how this can be possibly done.

Comment: Do you have to use memoir for a journal paper?

Comment: It's my first time that I'm using LaTeX and since I wanted to have the `roman` numbering for the contents and abstract, I've been suggested to use the `\mainmatter` and therefore the `memoir` package. Moreover I've taken advantage also of the double spacing functionality (which I tweaked in order to double space also the footnotes). So, since the deadline is terribly close, I'm just looking for an easy way of numbering my whole article. Next time I'll do things better from the beginning!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you say that `lineno` cannot be used with `memoir`? I couldn't find any reference to this in the `lineno` documentation nor in the `memoir` manual. The only problem I see is that `lineno` doesn't number footnote text, but this is not for `memoir`, but also for the standard classes.

To number footnote text too, you can use [`lineno`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lineno) *and* [`fnlineno`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fnlineno) (for numbering foornotes):

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fnlineno}

\linenumbers

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\section{Test section}
\lipsum*[1-3] test\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: LOL, you're just awesome.  
What I had tried was [this](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/Run2Physics/WWW/templates/lineno.html) procedure, which throw me a `! LaTeX Error: Command \linenumberfont already defined.` in the `memoirl.cls`, line 4842, and `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \vlvnumfont9999 ...towidth{\bvnumlength}{\vlvnumfont 9999}`, line 12771, and other `Badbox` warning. Then I commented out my macro, so everything was just not working (stress doesn't help).  
But the way, there is no need to include `\linenumbers` in the footnote ;)

Comment: I might have found a bug. If you compile once you have two different numbering, one for the body text and one for the footnote, throughout the whole document. If you compile a second time, the numbering is merged **but** it resets at every page! Moreover, captions are not included in the numbering.. is there any workaround for it?

Comment: @Atcold `fnlineno` forces page numbering to be made pagewise; since you said you don't need footnote text numbered, don't load `fnlineno` and you'll have continuous numbering for the document. The issue with captions might be a little more involved, I suggest you to open a new fresh question about this issue.

Comment: Hum, what I said is that `fnlineo` will automatically line-number the footnotes without specifying the command `\linenumbers` within the footnote itself (now I'm updating the code in your answer). Now, do you know, from the top of your head, if it is possible to do not reset the numbering while keeping using `fnlineo`?

Comment: @Atcold no, off the top of my head I wouldn't know. Consider opening a fresh new question. Thanks for editing the code :-)